# How to encode a grid of 9 gray pixels intensity into a single number?

Tags: python, opencv

So I have 9 pixels on a square grid. Each one is 0..255 (a shade of grey image). I want to get a kind of fingerprint out from it. I have 20 possible options, and I want to find the closest to a given image.

- 4 types of center fill,
- 6 types of line fill,
- 2 types of angled fill,
- 4 types of direction fill
- 4 types of cross fill

like this:

[image]

So how to get to which one of 20 my current given image is the closest?

Comment: The problem is interesting, but your question lacks research effort. What have you tried? What are the issues your current implementation is facing? As it stands, it seems more like a code request. What's the image you have to compare against this dataset? You mention you need to “find the closest to a given image”, you are in need of a similarity metric between the input image and this dataset. However, you do not provide enough debugging details. The solution could range from histogram comparison, template matching, to more elaborated feature matching.

Comment: The brute force way of doing it is creating 20 different kernels then using `cv2.morphologyEx` with [`cv2.MORPH_HITMISS`](https://vovkos.github.io/doxyrest-showcase/opencv/sphinx_rtd_theme/page_tutorial_hitOrMiss.html). For instance your first kernel for #0 would be something like `kernel = np.array(([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]), dtype="int")`. For #1 it would be like `kernel = np.array(([0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]), dtype="int")`

Comment: @stateMachine: I have computed row\column sums of pixels with values higher than 128, and same for my patterns/fingerprints, yet it seems not to solve it on diagonal cases. So I wondered if there is a non-manual - some standard OpenCV way of doing such things than writing 20 if-else cases and summing row\col values manually.

Comment: @nathancy: great! sounds like that is exactly what I need, could you please share an example of figuring out if an image is fitting a pattern in python?

Comment: Please show an example image that you want to compare and find the best match? Is it 3x3 pixels also? Is it binary pattern or grayscale?

Comment: @fmw42: yes they all are resized to 3x3, grayscale

Comment: How about encoding each 3x3 template as a string of 0s and 1s. Then take your 3x3 grayscale image and threshold it at 50% and do the same encoding. Then use the hamming distance to compute a difference metric.